# What is the prototype of an object created after setting <constructor>.prototype to null?

Tags: javascript-objects, prototypal-inheritance

I was learning how constructors work in JS and played around with the following code. I was expecting `bar` to be an object whose prototype is `null` but that is not the case.

```js
function foo() {}
foo.prototype = null;
let bar = new foo();
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(bar) === null);  // false
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(bar) === foo.prototype);  //false. Why?
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(bar)); // What is bar.[[Prototype]]?
```

Why isn't `bar.[[Prototype]]` `null`?

And what is `bar.[[Prototype]]` in this case? (Logging it to the console by running the above code snippet gives `{}`. In Node I got `[Object: null prototype] {}`.)